# Angular cli with webpack: not refreshing executed code with build?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I'm building an angular-cli based web app. I had an error in my chrome developer tools console, which I think is now resolved in my code. However when I rebuild and refresh my browser (and even delete my browser cache), I still see the error!

The error has to do with a shared component I am importing from an external library that I'm building.

Here it is:

```
compiler.es5.js:1689 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AuthService: (?, [object Object]).
at syntaxError (compiler.es5.js:1689)
at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15756)
at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15624)
at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15610)
at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15901)
at compiler.es5.js:15830
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15790)
at compiler.es5.js:15365
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

When I run `ng serve --prod`, the error disappears and my code runs beautifully.
Then, if I run `ng serve` again, without the `--prod`, I see the error again.

This is driving me nuts.

What might be causing this? Does webpack cache? If so, how can I refresh so my newest code is being run?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It may be helpful to post your actual error.

Comment: @pzaenger , I have edited the question, added the error in. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen too (not always though). By default, the browser caches the bundles, and when you use `ng serve`, the name of your bundle remains the same. The reason you don't see this error with `ng serve -prod` is that each production build has a different hash code in the bundle name so the browser doesn't use the cached version.

If you run the browser in the incognito mode you shouldn't have this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the input here. I don't think that's the issue, since I'm seeing the error when I open my site in FF as well as Chrome. And I haven't used FF in a while... Also, deleting my cache doesn't help, which it normally would in cases where using incognito mode helps... Any other ideas?